# React native webview HTML5 video sound not working in IOS silent mode

Tags: react-native, webview, react-native-ios

I am using WebView to load a webpage which has an embedded video player. It works fine when the app is in ringer mode. But does not have any sound when App is in silent mode. I am not well aware of IOS. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 <WebView startInLoadingState={true} 
    mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={false}    
    javaScriptEnabled={ true }                        
    source={{uri:'http://ab24.live/player'}}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't comment yet, just adding that it's been fixed (last comment of [github issue](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/211#issuecomment-491549543)).

So in order to avoid needing to call that hacky workaround function, now you just need to add `useWebKit={true}` to the WebView component.

Fix was implemented last month and should work with Expo V32+ versions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using [expo](https://expo.io) and you have come up against [this bug](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/211), you can get around this problem using the following:

```
import { Audio } from "expo";

...
  async playInSilentMode() {
    // To get around the fact that audio in a `WebView` will be muted in silent mode
    // See: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/211
    //
    // Based off crazy hack to get the sound working on iOS in silent mode (ringer muted/on vibrate)
    // https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/211#issuecomment-454319601
    await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
      playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
      allowsRecordingIOS: false,
      interruptionModeIOS: Audio.INTERRUPTION_MODE_IOS_MIX_WITH_OTHERS,
      shouldDuckAndroid: false,
      interruptionModeAndroid: Audio.INTERRUPTION_MODE_ANDROID_DO_NOT_MIX,
      playThroughEarpieceAndroid: true
    });
    // console.log("  done: setAudioModeAsync");
    await Audio.setIsEnabledAsync(true);
    // console.log("  done: setIsEnabledAsync");
    const sound = new Audio.Sound();
    await sound.loadAsync(
      require("./500-milliseconds-of-silence.mp3") // from https://github.com/anars/blank-audio
    );
    // console.log("  done: sound.loadAsync");
    await sound.playAsync();
    sound.setIsMutedAsync(true);
    sound.setIsLoopingAsync(true);
    // console.log("  done: sound.playAsync");
  }
```

Then, reference this in `componentDidMount()`:

```
  async componentDidMount() {
    await playInSilentMode();
  }
```